# Does my common-collector current amplifier work correctly?

Tags: rf, antenna, power-amplifier, common-collector

I have just built a 9V common-collector current amplifier to make my RF receiver more sensitive for 1-8Mhz. I used a voltage source in this circuit to make it clear how the circuit might work. The circuit begins with a preamplifier. The sine input is 1uV, meaning this is theoretical more and less in practice. I think it is realistic in certain cases to take this value in serious, because I have just a copper antenna with coil at the bottom. That means, I could work also with 100nV and below, but then the curves are getting a bit mismatched. As you can see in the graph, the current is exactly what it is in the input. The current measure for R8 begins with 34.274mA and goes up till 34.288mA, while the source starts at nano-amperes. That means there is a 14uA difference to get a reasonable result. Can you give the reason when I click upon "antenna", why I cannot get a current as result? Because of misunderstanding? Is this circuit useful in practical sense? Values tested in LTSpice.

[image: circuit]

[image: graph]

Comment: An antenna is far, far from ever being regarded as a voltage source.

Comment: Well, It is just an electromagnetic item, I think. It could be a source with db strength. Can you clarify the difference, if it is so. Thanks for comment.

Comment: It cannot be regarded as a voltage source in your circuit.

Comment: Well, it is not the 9Volt DC, but the sine input in this circuit to simulate.

Comment: This is incorrect: *I used a voltage source in this circuit to make it clear how the circuit might work with an alternative RF source, for example an antenna.* no matter how much you protest.

Comment: ok, i will correct and edit that. Just made it fine, I suppose.

Comment: Many times when I built circuits like the one above, there are complex lines up and down, some sort of complex current flows. I could not reason this. Therefore the question.

Comment: How can current flow in/out **antenna** node?...it is an open circuit...current is zero. I think this label is confusing - I'd imagine the right-most point goes to the receiver's input...the antenna would be connected where OP's **V2** sits - at the extreme left. Conventional circuit drawings show signal flow from left-to-right.

Comment: Most antenna whips are too short for this frequency range, so your basic idea of a common-collector preamp (which accepts input from a high-impedance whip and sends output to low-impedance receiver) is valid. A version that meets your needs: http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/0109031.pdf . Unfortunately, this preamp *must be placed* right at the whip, not at the receiver - so feeding it with DC power is complicated...the coax carries both DC and RF signal. Lots of toroid coils, and transformers, which some folks detest.

Comment: Why is R8 only 10 ohms? It causes R1 to be overloaded reducing voltage gain, and also reduces the maximum undistorted output.. Try 100 ohms or 1k ohms for R8.

Comment: What is all the stuff on the left side of the circtuit? Everything to the left of out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a current plot when you click on **antenna** because **antenna** is a node and in LTspice clicking a node will plot a voltage. To plot a current you have to click on a component that has a current flowing through it such as you did when plotting the current in R8.

As for the circuit being useful, I would say no. You appear to be throwing together different circuit topologies in an attempt to make an RF amplifier, but they mostly look like audio frequency circuits. For example as I pointed out in another of your questions 10\$\mu\$F capacitors are not usually found in the signal path of an RF circuit, common values would be under 1\$\mu\$F. For the HF range you normally see nF to *maybe* a couple of \$\mu\$F at the lowest freqs, in VHF and UHF you get down into pF.

If you want to build RF circuits you need to put a bit of time into studying them, amateur radio operators and organizations have some good resources. For RF amps you might look at the [BITX project](https://www.hfsignals.com/). They have [schematics and circuit descriptions](https://www.hfsignals.com/index.php/ubitx-circuit-description/) and use a three transistor broadband amplifier throughout their designs that might be adaptable to your needs.

Comment: Well, I have just made an experiment at home to see if the amplifier circuit is working at all and I have just soldered the components together. I added antenna, coil, quartz and diode to the input of the circuit and to the output added finally my earphone. I tried to transmit a sound over an 8MHz transmitter, and I recognized that it works. The sound is not loud but can be made out. The only thing that can be useful up to now, is to get a LM386 to amplify the sound. I will check this out tonight. I will make you know, how things change. Thanks for help.